# How to read this if conditional in PHP?

Tags: php, session

This part of the code are from my session login scripts

```
$logins = array('BUDI' => 'BUDI', 'ANDI' => 'ANDI', 'AISYAH' => 'AISYAH', 'FINA' => 'FINA');

$username = isset($_POST['uname']) ? $_POST['uname'] : '';
$password = isset($_POST['pass']) ? $_POST['pass'] : '';
```

**My main question**

Right below the code above, there is this if statement
.Is this code read like "if there is username and username match the password which the key on the array, then do the following." ?

```
if (isset($logins[$username]) && $logins[$username] == $password)
```

Fyi, username and password i create are stored in associative array

Comment: From left to right - And yes

Comment: Yeah i know but, what i want to know is what this code really mean? 
$logins[$username] == $password

Comment: You are testing the values passed in $_POST (from the form) against the existance of that username and that the password passed in $_POST matches the one held on your array

Comment: Do you have a probelm with what it is doing, or not doing?

Comment: Well that's simply a comparison. The isset checks if there _is_ an entry in $logins under the key $username, and if so, it checks if the value associated with that key, is equal to that of $password. (This would probably be a bit easier to grasp, if the keys and values in your array were actually different. Right now, username (the key) and password (the value) are exactly the same, for each entry.)